# How to find code that's running in a Batch Job

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to support our Dynamics AX 2009 environment.

I'm trying to troubleshoot a possible issue with a Batch Job.

So I'm going in Basic/Inquiries/Batch jobs.

From there, I can see all configured batch jobs. But I'm at a loss to find what class methods/jobs/batches they're actually calling so I can browse the X++ that's being executed for each of them.

I went in "View tasks" but nothing significant there either.

I also went in the AOT/Jobs but I can't find anything remotely looking like the "Job Description" field in Basic/Inquiries/Batch jobs.

Comment: Well, it was staring me in the face. After clicking "View Tasks" the "Class Name" contains the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the batch job screen, you can click on the "View Tasks" button. This will then show you the class name  of the task. You must then go to the AOT and navigate to classes and then find the class that was in the class name field. That should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Solution for AX 3.0 and 4.0: [How can I identify an Axapta class Name from the class ID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/177357/1380473)